# Snowflake sub query not supported

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Id like to run a query where i look to see if product ids exist from a trial products table, and also if this product id exists in a discounts table, and then create a flag based on this.
but im faced with the error 'unsupported sub query type'.

my code is as follows:

```
select a.*, b.address,
  case when (a.product in ((select distinct product from trial_products)) and a.product not in ((select distinct product from discount_table))) then 'Indirect' 
  when (a.product in ((select distinct product  from trial_product )) and a.product in ((select distinct product from discount_table))) then 'Direct'
  else Null end as DirectIndirectFlag
  from 
salesTable a
left join 
all_products b 
on a.product= b.product
```

How can i run this case when statement by nesting a query? Im using snowflake for this query.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CTE and joins to make this work.

```
with trial_p as (
  select distinct product 
  from trial_products
), disc_p as (
  select distinct product 
  from discount_table
)
select a.*, b.address,
  case 
     when trial_p.product is not null and disc_p.product is null then 'Indirect' 
     when trial_p.product is not null and disc_p.product is not null then 'Direct'
     else Null 
  end as DirectIndirectFlag
from salesTable a
left join trial_p on a.product = trial_p.product
left join disc_p on a.product = disc_p.product
left join all_products b on a.product= b.product
```

Comment: this is exactly the sort of thing i am looking for! however the syntax of trial_p.product calls invalid identifier in snowflake. i dont think you can use the dot method to access a variable

Comment: @milo204 there's a typo in one of the cases `when tiral_p`

Comment: @milo204 -- I fixed the typo -- I had i and r swapped

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. even with the fixed typo, i dont think this method is something that snowflake accepts- using {table}.{variable}

Comment: @milo204 -- of course that works you have it in 10 places in your code.  It is table column name

Comment: thanks, to get it to work i had to change it to

Comment: `case 

     when b.product is not null and c.product is null then 'Indirect' 

     when b.product is not null and c.product is not null then 'Direct'

     else Null
 
  end as DirectIndirectFlag

from salesTable a

left join trial_p as b on a.product = b.product

left join disc_p as c on a.product = c.product

left join all_products as b on a.product= b.product
`
appreciate your help

Comment: @milo204 -- your sample code makes no sense you have two tables with an alias of b

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use EXISTS and nest your CASEs to avoid redundant subqueries:

```
select 
    a.*, 
    b.address,
    case 
        when exists (select 1 from trial_products t where t.product = a.product) then
            case
                when exists (select 1 from discount_table d where d.product = a.product) then 'Direct'
                else 'Indirect'
            end 
        else Null 
    end as DirectIndirectFlag
from 
    salesTable a
    left join 
    all_products b on a.product = b.product
```

Comment: thanks, ive never seen a nested case before so struggling to get this to work- obtaining syntax error for unexpected when and then for the first line of the case!